# Looping list null elements

Tags: c#, linq, list, class

I have a list  containing instances of a class (People). As time passes, some people will disappear (made null in list), and others added. Then I want to loop through the list of elements that are not null.

The code below does the job, but I feel like it's pretty poorly written.

1. I have a list with many null elements. Is that even an issue? With he current code it's manageable. But if I change `createPerson(10);` to `createPerson(300);`, and `for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)`, my list will have a Count of ~6300 elements, of which 6000 are null.
2. Going through the list element by element and checking `if (person[i] != null)` seems silly. Any other way to do this? Should LINQ be used here?

I'm thinking maybe it'd be better to remove null elements, and move the elements with data to elements with null. Then I'd need to use `person.Id` (a unique incremental ID), rather than the index number, to identify the element. Similar to:

```
var item = person.First(i => i.Id == Id);
```

Is there any recommended approach for this issue?

**Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace listID
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<People> person = new List<People>();
        static Random rnd = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Generates 10 people of random ages.
            createPerson(10);

            // Advances 100 years.
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                circleOfLife();
            }

            writeList();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Writes out the current elements in the list
        /// </summary>
        static void writeList()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < person.Count; i++)
            {
                if (person[i] != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("List index: " + i + " -  " + person[i].age + " years old.");
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates people of random age between 0 and 100.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="q">Amount of people to create</param>
        static void createPerson(int q)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= q; i++)
            {
                People newPerson = new People();
                newPerson.age = rnd.Next(100);
                person.Add(newPerson);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases age of person by a year. If person reaches age of 100, they get removed, and another one of random age is added.
        /// </summary>
        static void circleOfLife()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < person.Count; i++)
            {
                if(person[i] != null)
                {
                    person[i].increaseAge();
                    if (person[i].age > 99)
                    {
                        person[i] = null;
                        createPerson(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class People
    {
        public int age;

        private static int m_Counter = 0;
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public People()
        {
            this.Id = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref m_Counter); // Gives unique incrememntal ID number to each elelment.
        }

        public void increaseAge()
        {
            age++;
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> List index: 13 -  93 years old.
> List index: 17 -  26 years old.
> List index: 18 -  95 years old.
> List index: 19 -  45 years old.
> List index: 20 -  34 years old.
> List index: 21 -  92 years old.
> List index: 22 -  58 years old.
> List index: 23 -  44 years old.
> List index: 24 -  67 years old.
> ```

Help is very appreciated. I'm still learning so example code would be very useful.

Comment: Your paragraph starting “I'm thinking maybe ...” is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Yeah, it does make sense to me. I would however appreciate a code example showing how to call same instance before and after using `circleOfLife();`. Like if one instance `person[x]` with property `person[x].Id = y` getsassigned a new index (z), I would need to find the element containing property `person.Id = y`. What would be the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you *substitute* people instead of assigning to `null` and adding?

```
 static void circleOfLife() {
   for (int i = 0; i < persons.Count; ++i) {
     persons[i].increaseAge();

     // if a person is too old  
     if (persons[i].age > 99) {
       // ...generate a new person and put it on old person's place
       persons[i] = new People() {
         age = rnd.Next(100)
       }; 
     }
   } 
 }
```

In this case you'll get rid of pesky `null` checks.

Answer (score 1):

Whether your list should contain `null` values for person objects with `Age > 99` or not depends on what you want to express in your domain model.

But I cannot imagine a good reason why to keep `null` values in the list. What additional information does the existence of null values  convey. The information about "who these persons were" is lost, because the id is gone with its instance. If you want to keep track about how many people existed over all times, then a simple counter would be sufficient. So these `null` values only lead to a ever increasing list and slow down the performance over time.

If you want to keep track about person instances with their ids that "are too old" then you could work with two lists with "living persons" and one list to store historic instances.

Some useful LINQ expressions as examples:

```
var livingPeople = people.Where(p => p != null && p.Age <= 99);
people.RemoveAll(p => p == null); // removes all null values
var numberOfPassedPeople = people.Count(p => p == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to remove element from the list using RemoveAll.

```
static void circleOfLife()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < person.Count; i++)
    {
        if(person[i] != null)
        {
            person[i].increaseAge();
        }
    }
    //Select all id of person having Age > 99
    var personIds = person.Where(p => p.Age > 99).Select(p => p.Id);
    person.RemoveAll(p => p.Age > 99); //or person.RemoveAll(p => personIds.Contains(p.Id));
    createPerson(personIds.Count());
}
```

It will select all the person with Age > 99 then remove it from the list.

Comment: No `RemoveAll` is a method of `List` that accepts a *predicate*. Not related with Linq

Comment: That clears out the undesired elements. But if I want to refer to a specific instance in that case, I would have to use person.Id to keep track of them, right? (Since the index will be changing) What would be the best way to do that? Linq, or using FindIndex?

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ `Where()` extension method and get only the non null ones like

```
var item = person.Where(p => p != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Lookup`:

```
var lookup = person.Where(p => p != null && p.Age <= 99).ToLookup(p => p.Id);    
var item = lookup[42].FirstOrDefault(); // null if no person with Id 42
```